# Python Pandas - Using space as a delimiter but some rows have spaces in each item

Tags: python, pandas

I have these sample raw input which I want to make a dataframe.

```
data = """SomeFile FixedCode
TestFile CustomCode
algorithm-tester CustomCode
algorithm-tester-header CustomCode
project Code Break CustomCode  # Problematic row
...
"""
```

which I could plug into a dataframe using

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=" ", on_bad_lines="warn",...)
```

The line above can build my desired dataframe, however unable to process the problematic lines similar to the one above. The problematic rows sometimes contains more than 2 spaces because of the name in the first column. Is it possible to handle these kinds of outliers within the pandas module? Or does this needs pre-processing to handle those outliers before passing it to the dataframe?

Expected dataframe below:

```
                           0          1
0    TestFile                FixedCode
1    algorithm-tester        CustomCode
2    algorithm-tester-header CustomCode
3    project Code Break      CustomCode
...
```

Comment: Using `pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))` I obtain the desired output...

Comment: You have to use newline as separator and for each record, split by space, and the last split part of array would be your CustomCode or FixedCode.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago what you're saying is that I need to pre-process the data first before plugging it in the dataframe?

Comment: if you would have more spaces as separator then you could use regex like `sep="( ){2,}"` to split on two or more spaces.

Comment: if you would know widths of columns then you could try to use `read_fwf()` (`fixed-width format`)

Comment: @Dense04 I mean that use newline as separator and when reading each line, do that split to an array, as I said in last command. please add your sample code. Good luck.

Comment: @Dense04 if you have after 'TestFile', 'Custom Code', as you specified in the file, then my answer option is below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all lines ending with "Custom Code". Use the word 'Custom Code' as a separator. Read the file, split the column name into two words. Next, I copy what got into the index and create a column 'Fixed Code' with the same string 'Customercode'. I reset indexes and delete unnecessary columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('SomeFile.csv', header=0,sep="CustomCode", engine = 'python')

name_columns = str(df.columns[0]).split()
df[0] = df.index
df[1] = "CustomCode"
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop(columns=['index', 'SomeFile FixedCode'])

print(df)
```

Input

```
                          SomeFile FixedCode
TestFile                                 NaN
algorithm-tester                         NaN
algorithm-tester-header                  NaN
project Code Break                       NaN
```

Output

```
                          0           1
0                 TestFile   CustomCode
1         algorithm-tester   CustomCode
2  algorithm-tester-header   CustomCode
3       project Code Break   CustomCode
```